# Text to columns comma-delimited problem with tabs

Tags: vba

I am converting "text to columns" numerous .txt files that are comma delimited. A small number of lines have [TAB]s in them. Those lines are deleting everything on that line after the tab when I convert using my text-to-columns macro.

I have tried both "TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone" and "TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote," hoping one of those was the issue, but neither is corrective. Below is my code:

```
Sub Text2ColsAX()
'
' Text2ColsAX Macro
'

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range

Set wsCopy = Application.ActiveSheet

With wsCopy
    Set rngCopy = .Range("a2:a" & .Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row)

    rngCopy.Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 5), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), _
        Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 2 _
        ), Array(14, 2), Array(15, 2), Array(16, 2), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 5), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), _
        Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 2 _
        ), Array(14, 2), Array(15, 2), Array(16, 2), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 2), Array(19, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End With

End Sub
```

A line with the following:

```
"1 2345678 some words with TAB HERE>     901234 morewords,mm/dd/yyyy,moretext,moretext,1234.56,,E1234,0000,000,123456,00000,000000"
```

becomes:

```
"1 2345678 some words with TAB HERE>"
```

Double quotes are not part of text. They only indicate where the line of text begins and where it ends.

Comment: The second text to column statement is meant to clear out the original text-to-columns formatting because it was causing issues with other copy-paste functions.

Comment: You could replace the tabs before performing the text-to-columns.  Unless you need them.

Comment: `rngCopy.Replace What:=vbTab, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: That's a possibility. The only thing that needs to be untouched is the original .txt file. Have any clue why it might perform this way?